# Parse two arrays to check each value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

So i have two lists.

List A contains a list of all dates of a specified month. list B contains a sequence of 1 and 0´s. If i want to check if date from list A is equal to 1 or 0 corresponding to the position in list B, How should i approach this?.

The idea is to check if day 1,2,3.. and so on is value 1 or 0 from List B..

Example 2020-02-01 = 1 or 0...

```js
var listDate = [];
var startDate ='2020-02-01';
var endDate = '2020-02-29';
var dateMove = new Date(startDate);
var strDate = startDate;

while (strDate < endDate){
  var strDate = dateMove.toISOString().slice(0,10);
  var dayCount = listDate.length;
  listDate.push(strDate);
  dateMove.setDate(dateMove.getDate()+1);
};
console.log(dayCount + 1)
console.log(listDate)
```

Then i have another list that contains a sequence of 1 and 0 ´s.

```js
var str = "1100000110000011000001100000100";
var res = str.split("");
var n = str.length;

console.log(n)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: What if there is no corresponding index  of 100100101 ? Will there always be 31 11110000?

Comment: And the problem is? Iterate over `listDate` and check if at the current index in `res` is a `"1"` or not.

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, yes the sequence is always 31

Comment: @Andreas The problem is that i want to have a result of all days of specified month whether or not the date is a 1 or 0, however the sequence is always 31 at any give month so i need exclude the trailing 0s. So i want a result of , date 2020-02-01 is 1 or 0 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
const res = "1100000110000011000001100000100".split("");


var listDate = [];
var startDate ='2020-02-01';
var endDate = '2020-02-29';
var dateMove = new Date(startDate);
var strDate = startDate;

while (strDate < endDate){
  var strDate = dateMove.toISOString().slice(0,10);
  var dayCount = listDate.length;
  listDate.push(strDate);
  dateMove.setDate(dateMove.getDate()+1);
};

// code based on day number rather than the place in the array

listDate.forEach(dt => console.log(dt,res[dt.split("-")[2]-1]))
let weekdays = listDate.filter(dt => res[dt.split("-")[2]-1]==="0")
let weekends = listDate.filter(dt => res[dt.split("-")[2]-1]==="1")
console.log(weekends)

// same code based on index

listDate.forEach((dt,i) => console.log(dt,res[i]))
weekdays = listDate.filter((dt,i) => res[i]==="0")
weekends = listDate.filter((dt,i) => res[i]==="1")
console.log(weekends)
```

Comment: Sorry if my post is a bit diffuse. I would like to check each date om specified month of the dates in that month corresponds to a 1 or 0.

Comment: Ok, so i want a result telling me that date 2020-02-01 is equal to 1 or 0 but i want the result to be like 2020-02-01 = 01, 2020-02-02 = 0, 2020-02-03 = 0, and so on.

Comment: 2020-02-02 = 1, not 0

Comment: Yes! Thank you. This is perfect

Comment: See update for different usage of index or day number

Answer (score 1):

```
listDate.filter((_,i) => str[i]==='1')
```

will give you the dates where you have a 1 in the 'binary list'

```
listDate.map((date,i) => [date,str[i]])
```

will give you a new list with sublists [date,"1 or 0"]

```
listDate.map((date,i) => [date,str[i]==='1'])
```

will give you a new list with sublists [date,true or false]

Comment: Thanks, this could work actually. Becuse my reason is to exclude all working days (0s) in the end.